# Dropdown from large range (~50k) in google sheets, can it be done?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to let the user select a single value from a rather large dataset (~50k items), in a "search-as-you-type" fashion. For this I created a range for the values, and then a data validation rule with a dropdown linked to it. Like this:

[image]

Unfortunately this becomes way too slow, my sheet crashes and burns as soon as the range is about 10k entries or more.

Is there some way I could get this to work, or is searching among this many items in this fashion just "too much"?

Comment: What is the specific cell data type? Formula, text, number?

Comment: The cell type is text

Comment: Sadly, other than ordering the column alphabetically and praying that this optimizes it, I don't think there's a solution. :/

Comment: Is the sheet crashing when loading the dropdown list from the cell, or is it happening while building the list in the data validation side panel?

Comment: Usually while building it in the side panel. With about 10k items the dropdown is built, but performance is sluggish when using the dropdown.

Comment: I'm surprised that you even got to 10K let alone 50K. In fact, I've never heard of a dropdown with so many options - it does seem extraordinary. Is there an as aspect of this task that could be approached differently so that the dropdowns are added incrementally?

Comment: Sure! That would be more cumbersome for the user, but if nothing else works :)

Comment: I should add that I am willing to write apps script code if that could solve this. 
But I have found no way that would let me display results to choose from as the user types in search text, since its not possible to get any notifications for typed text in a cell. There is only a notification for when the entire cell value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior/limitation of the Google Sheets since 50k is a lot for a data validation.

**Workaround:**

Here's a suggestion.
You can divide the options into multiple categories and make use of different columns. For example if the options are Apple, Mango, Watermelon, Lettuce, Cabbage, Broccoli, you can divide this into Fruits and Vegetables. Only if the fruits category is selected then he will have the next cell to select from the options available in the fruits category. For this you will need to use Apps Script. This will greatly improve the performance of your sheet since the options will not all be available at once and will only appear when a certain category is selected.

Comment: Let me know if you have questions. I am willing to guide and point you to the right direction.